# Are node.js require file names case sensitive on linux?

Tags: node.js

Are those two Node.js calls equal on Linux with case-sensitive file-system?

```
require("./Name")
```

**AND**

```
require("./name")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they are not. I would make this answer shorter, just "No", but SO makes me type no less than 30 chars.